# How to respond image data to only authenticated user in Blazor application?

Tags: .net-core, blazor

In my Blazor application, I have written an authentication logic using LocalStorage. However, I need to my the application responds image data to authorized users. I think that Blazor can not realize it.

So, I'd like to coexist an MVC controller in a Blazor application and use the same user authentication, but the Blazor's authentication logic does not work in MVC controller.

Do you have any good ideas? The authentication logic does not need to use LocalStorage, but BASIC authentication is unacceptable.

---

I tried:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    AuthenticationStateProvider Auth;
    public RawFileController(AuthenticationStateProvider auth)
    {
        Auth = auth;
    }
    [HttpGet("...")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MyGet()
    {
        var authState = await Auth.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(authState);
        Console.WriteLine(authState.User);
        Console.WriteLine(authState.User.Identity);
        Console.WriteLine(authState.User.Identity.Name); // output empty !!
        ...
    }
}
```

My `AuthenticationStateProvider` is [here](https://github.com/kjmtks/LMS7/blob/master/ALMS.App/Services/AuthStateProvider.cs).

My `Startup.cs` is [here](https://github.com/kjmtks/LMS7/blob/master/ALMS.App/Startup.cs).

Could you give me any suggestions?

My concrete code is here: https://github.com/kjmtks/LMS7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At MVC side create a login (.cshtml) and have user available in HttpContext.
In Blazor side, you can use `AuthenticationStateProvider`.

```
var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
var user = authState.User;
```

You can wrap your image for authenticated user with:

```
       <AuthorizeView> <Authorized> ... <Authorized> </AuthorizeView>
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable advice.
I will try it!!

Comment: Do you have any document that will help me understanding your advice in detail?

Comment: Your advice is correct.
I have been able to achieve my goal.

Comment: @kjmtks thanks for your feedback. Please mark my solution as accepted so that others see value in the answer.